# Convert each element in a list to a corresponding (predefined) dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[The coding challenge from Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/550f22f4d758534c1100025a/train/python)

I want to map each corresponding value in an array to my new defined dictionary such that

```
'NORTH': 1, 'SOUTH': -1, 'EAST': 1, 'WEST': -1
```

Here, each key corresponds to a an individual element in a given `list` and the values in the `dict` is what I want the new elements of said `list` to equal to.

I then intend on taking the sum of the new `list` to find the "reduced direction"

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Show us your code and where you get stuck first.

Comment: I don't have a draft of a working code. I couldn't find other posts here that might clarify my query and solutions posted online used a different method @sal

Comment: At least show and example of the expected output for a given input,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
>>> src = ['NORTH','SOUTH','EAST','EAST']
>>> adict = {'NORTH': 1, 'SOUTH': -1, 'EAST': 1, 'WEST': -1}
>>> sum(map(adict.__getitem__,src))
2
>>>
```